# android mediaplayer side playing other side to cache

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Android mediaplayer online music, for the first time is side playing side to cache, later is directly to play the local music, our resources are mp3, I now are two threads, one playing one downloading. The mainstream players how to implement, can obtain mediaplayer own PCM format cache data, then turn code into mp3 format? Or customize a mediaplayer?
By the way my English is so poor embarrassed  mediaPlayer.

```
mMediaPlayer.reset();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+  File.separator + "music",
playMusicDataBean.music_id + ".mp3");
            if (file.exists()) {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(playMusicDataBean.url);
                new Thread() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(playMusicDataBean.url);
                            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                            if (in == null)
                                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
                            // File file =
                            // File.createTempFile("player_mp3_cache",
                            // ".mp3",
                            // MainActivity.this.getCacheDir());
                            File file = new File(
                                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                            + File.separator + "nyx"
                                            + File.separator + "music",
                                    playMusicDataBean.music_id + ".mp3");
                            if (!file.exists())
                                file.createNewFile();
//                          if(file.exists())
//                              file.delete();
                            m_strTempFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                            System.out.println(m_strTempFilePath);
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            byte buffer[] = new byte[128];
                            do {
                                int nNumRead = in.read(buffer);
                                if (nNumRead <= 0)
                                    break;
                                fos.write(buffer);
                            } while (true);
                            // m_player.setDataSource(m_strTempFilePath);
                            in.close();
                            fos.close();
                            // playMusicDataBean.isLoaded=true;
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }.start();
            } mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: can you show some code of what you've already tried?

Comment: The two threads one playing one downloading has made , feeling the mainstream player treatment methods are not like that, so I want to ask next